# I'm trying to make a wifi bruteforce cracker and im facing this indentation error

Tags: python, hash, wifi, password-encryption, brute-force

So I'm trying to make a functional brute force cracker for fun without using hashcat or whatever to test my own knowledge, my goal here is to make a code that would connect me when I enter the wifi name but instead of entering the password I altered it into brute force cracking it. Would that work in theory? Here's my code:

```
    import os
import random
import string

# function to establish a new connection
def createNewConnection(name, SSID, password):
    config = """<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> 
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"> 
    <name>"""+name+"""</name> 
    <SSIDConfig> 
        <SSID> 
            <name>"""+SSID+"""</name> 
        </SSID> 
    </SSIDConfig> 
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType> 
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode> 
    <MSM> 
        <security> 
            <authEncryption> 
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication> 
                <encryption>AES</encryption> 
                <useOneX>false</useOneX> 
            </authEncryption> 
            <sharedKey> 
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType> 
                <protected>false</protected> 
                <keyMaterial>"""+password+"""</keyMaterial> 
            </sharedKey> 
        </security> 
    </MSM> 
</WLANProfile>"""
    command = "netsh wlan add profile filename=\""+name+".xml\""+" interface=Wi-Fi"
    with open(name+".xml", 'w') as file:
        file.write(config)
    os.system(command)

# function to connect to a network
def connect(name, SSID):
    command = "netsh wlan connect name=\""+name+"\" ssid=\""+SSID+"\" interface=Wi-Fi"
    os.system(command)

# function to display avavilabe Wifi networks
def displayAvailableNetworks():
    command = "netsh wlan show networks interface=Wi-Fi"
    os.system(command)


# display available netwroks
displayAvailableNetworks()

# input wifi name and get password
chars = string.printable
chars_list = list(chars)
name = input("Name of Wi-Fi: ")
while name != "Example name that no wifi will probably be":
    password = random.choices(chars_list, k=(len(password)))
    print("<===============|"+ str(password)+ "|===============>")
    if (password == list(password)):
        print("Your password is: "+ "".join(password))

    # establish new connection
    createNewConnection(name, name, password)

    # connect to the wifi network
    connect(name, name)
```

If this ever ends working Ill be very happy because I spent days trying to find an actual working Brute force and couldn't find anything, if this doesn't work in theory can someone direct me to a similar purpose source code? Thanks!

The error message now says that password isn't defined in the line that says k=len(password)

Comment: You haven't shown us the error message. It should tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: i just changed it!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
if (password == list(password)):
        print("Your password is: "+ "".join(password))
```

Change it to

```
if (password == list(password)):
    print("Your password is: "+ "".join(password))
```

Comment: that wasn't the indentation problem, I fixed that but now it says that the k=len(password) thing is undefined or the password inside the parenthesis is undefined

Answer (score 0):

In theory something like this could work. It is probably possible to connect to a WiFi network using python. Trying many passwords in a brute force fashion is also possible but definitely not very efficient if you don't have a wordlist or know at least the length of the password.

Regarding your Code:

The indentation error is here (as any linter would tell you):

```py
while name != "Example name that no wifi will probably be":
    password = random.choices(chars_list, k=(len(password)))
    print("<===============|"+ str(password)+ "|===============>")
if (password == list(password)):
        print("Your password is: "+ "".join(password))
        

# establish new connection
createNewConnection(name, name, password)

# connect to the wifi network
connect(name, name)
```

should be

```py
while name != "Example name that no wifi will probably be":
    password = random.choices(chars_list, k=(len(password)))
    print("<===============|"+ str(password)+ "|===============>")
    if (password == list(password)):
        print("Your password is: "+ "".join(password))

    # establish new connection
    createNewConnection(name, name, password)

    # connect to the wifi network
    connect(name, name)
```

I recommend that you use something other than
`name != "Example name that no wifi will probably be"`
for your loop. It should be some kind of `connected` variable being checked.

Comment: okay but now it says that k=len(password) is not defined so how do i fix that

Comment: Sorry, when I edited I accidentally removed the part where I mentioned that you cannot check the length of password before it's defined. 

```python
password = random.choices(chars_list, k=(len(password)))
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```